# iPhone and Apple Watch connectivity signal strength to detect how far they are from each others

Tags: ios, bluetooth, watchkit, core-bluetooth, watchos

I just want to detect the distance between iPhone and Apple watch. e.g. nearby, far and out of reach.

There is an iOS App Lookout which does that. I want to achieve that.

Comment: @BhumitMehta the question you mentioned is not being answered as well as its about 1 year old. There must be a solution for this now as Lookout achieved that.

Comment: You are right I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Did you try using iBeacon?

Comment: Yes I used iBeacons.